# Nginx ignoring the server name

Tags: nginx

I have two server blocks

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen 443 default_server ssl;
server_name www.example.com example.com;
root /var/www/webpage
index index.php;

client_max_body_size 3800m;

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

and

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name cloud.example.com;
  # enforce https
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name cloud.example.com;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

  # Add headers to serve security related headers
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; preload;";

  root /var/www/owncloud/;

  # set max upload size
  client_max_body_size 10G;
  fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

  rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

  index index.php;
  error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
  error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    }

  location ~ ^/(?:\.htaccess|data|config|db_structure\.xml|README){
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
   # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
   rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
   rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

   rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
   rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

   rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }

location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
   fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 8000M
   post_max_size = 8000M
   output_buffering = 0";
   fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
   }

   # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
   location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
      expires 30d;
      access_log off;
   }

}
```

but now, when I am visiting

```
https://example.com
```

nginx serves `/var/www/owncloud`.

For

```
https://www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

`/var/www/webpage` is served as desired.

Comment: Not sure this will fix the problem, but remove the second default_server from the ssl line - I've only ever seen one in the past. Try some basic problem solving - comment out one server block, restart, and test, then swap what's commented out.

Comment: Why are you mixing ```listen 80``` and ```listen 443``` in one server block?

Comment: @ALex_hha is this bad practice? I did this so that I dont have to repeat everything.

Comment: @Tim If I comment out the owncloud server block its serving all domains to the desired place. So in fact something causes this strange behaviour.

Comment: Listening on 80 and 443 is fine, delivers content on both ports, but better practice would be to have a separate server defined and forward all requests to https. You can download sample nginx configs that do this from my tutorial here, around half way down the page https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Remove *default_server*.

**This will receive all HTTP traffic for www.example.com and example.com.**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com example.com;
root /var/www/webpage
index index.php;
--other--config--here
}
```

**This will receive all HTTPS traffic for www.example.com and example.com.**

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name www.example.com example.com;
root /var/www/webpage
index index.php;
--other--config--here
}
```

Note that the above are 2 separate virtuals. Don't put 80 and 443 together. The above setup does not force redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

**For your owncloud, see below.**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name cloud.example.com;
  # enforce https
  return 301 https://cloud.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

*Note: indicate the domain in the redirect*

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name cloud.example.com;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
--other--config--here
}
```